# Lemma from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I begin to study group theory from Herstein's book because abstract algebra always was my weakest side in mathematics.

Given $a, b$ in the group $G$, then the equations $a\cdot x=b$ and $y\cdot a=b$ have unique solutions for $x$ and $y$ in $G$.

**Solution:** Suppose we have two solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ then: $a\cdot x_1=b$ and $a\cdot x_2=b$ and we get $a\cdot x_1=a\cdot x_2$ and after multiplying both sides to $a^{-1}$ we get: $x_1=x_2=a^{-1}\cdot b$

Right?

Comment: Right, that proves uniqueness. You should prove existence as well. (You can actually prove both at the same time by left-multiplying both sides of $a\cdot x = b$ by $a^{-1}$.)

Comment: You're right. A nice exercise now would be to prove the converse given that the operation is associative

Comment: Yes you are correct. When writing out such a proof at the start of your study of groups you will probably find it helpful to make explicit the fact that you are multiplying on the left and that you are using associativity to simplify the expression. This is how Herstein does it on (in my copy of the book) page 30.

Comment: @S.Dolan, Yes I have difenitely used associativity but I decided not to write it.